# Transformar áudio gravado em um vetor de bytes

Tags: android, android-layout, áudio

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e quero o seguinte:

Após o usuário gravar o áudio, ele clica em um botão que exibe o vetor de bytes do mesmo. Na verdade, preciso enxergar esse vetor, para depois utilizá-lo para um outra funcionalidade (exibir o espectro de frequência por meio de uma FFT).

**Para desenvolver a biblioteca Glide aparentemente está sendo utilizada.
Ela serve para exibição de imagens, só que eu não tenho certeza se serve para arquivos de áudio também. Poderiam me ajudar com isso?**

Mensagens de **erro** na *Logcat* que estou tendo:

```
02-06 14:28:39.510 27044-27044/? W/Glide: Load failed for /storage/emulated/0/e2180ce1-ec46-4a6f-8617-606964ded2deaudio_record.3gp with size [80x80]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{AssetFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AssetFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
02-06 14:28:45.739 27044-27044/? W/Glide: Load failed for /storage/emulated/0/e2180ce1-ec46-4a6f-8617-606964ded2deaudio_record.3gp with size [80x80]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{AssetFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AssetFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
02-06 14:28:45.740 27044-27044/? W/Glide: Load failed for /storage/emulated/0/e2180ce1-ec46-4a6f-8617-606964ded2deaudio_record.3gp with size [80x80]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{AssetFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AssetFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
```

**O meu problema está sendo especificamente em tentar entender essas mensagens de erro que estão aparecendo na janela da "Logcat".**

Abaixo está o meu **código**, para melhor entendimento e possíveis explicações do porquê estar ocorrendo os erros na janela da Logcat, conforme relatados acima.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declare variables
Button btnRecord, btnStopRecord, btnPlay, btnStop;
//String pathSave ="";
private static String pathSave;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE=1000;

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    //Request Runtime permission
    if(!checkPermissionFromDevice()){
        requestPermission();
    }


    //Init View
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartRecord);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnStopRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopRecord);



    btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){

            if (checkPermissionFromDevice())
            {

                pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";
                setupMediaRecorder();
                try{
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                }  catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);

                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //return pathSave;

            }

            else{

                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    });


   // final String pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";

   // Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);

   // intent.putExtra("key",pathSave);
   // startActivity(intent);

   // System.out.println(pathSave);
   // String myTag=null;
   // Log.d(myTag, "Salvo");

    btnStopRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            btnStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
            btnRecord.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            btnStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
            btnRecord.setEnabled(false);

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try{
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pathSave);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
            btnRecord.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);
            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);

            if (mediaPlayer != null){

                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                setupMediaRecorder();
            }
        }
    });


}

private void setupMediaRecorder(){
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathSave);
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new  String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    } ,REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE:
        {
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText( this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice(){
    int write_external_storage_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int record_audio_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    return write_external_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            record_audio_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

}



String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";

public byte[] convert(String path) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1; ) {
        bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
    }

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    //String msgDecode = new String(bytes); // tentando converter byte em String
    //System.out.println("Vetor de bytes [" + msgDecode + "]"); // Exibir

    String decode = Arrays.toString(bytes);
    Log.d("mytag", decode);

    return bytes;

    }

}
```

Obrigada!

Comment: decodificou o áudio em formato PCM ?

Comment: O meu arquivo de áudio está sendo gravado e depois salvo no formato ".3gp"

Comment: se vc não decodificar o arquivo não tem como extrair os dados no formato PCM para criar uma FFT depois

Comment: @ederwander  Com "decodificar" o arquivo, vc quer dizer "convertê-lo" em PCM, correto? Ou seja, é necessário converter esse arquivo do tipo ".3gp" em "PCM" para que seja possível aplicar uma FFT.

Comment: exatamente .. vc precisa dos dados em formato PCM e isso vc só consegue decodificando o áudio antes ...